# How to strengthen and remove knot near Brachialis and Biceps Brachii?

Tags: pain, biceps

I have a knot near the Brachialis and Biceps Brachii. It's been there for a few years now and haven't been able to get rid of it.  I've done arm workouts, theragun, foam rolling, and stretches.  Massages normally make it feel better for awhile but it always comes back.  What things should I focus on to improve that area?